# Parsing diffs (generated with git-diff) with PHP

Tags: php, diff

I need to parse diff files (as created by Git).

I've already tried Text_Diff from PEAR and "[PHP class for parsing diffs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061151/php-class-for-parsing-diffs)" solution.
However, both can only generate diffs themselves.

Does anyone know ready-made solution?

p.s.: writing simple diff-viewer script.

Comment: What's your question?  We're not going to write your entire script for you!!!

Comment: Sry. Maybe someone knows r-t-w solution?

Comment: @psynnott: in fairness, he was not asking for someone to write his script, but rather if something is out there already.

Answer (score 0):

There's the xdiff PHP extension.  Failing that, you can always exec() the actual diff commandline tools from within your script.

Comment: I can't find any info about **parsing** diff files. http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.xdiff.php.

Comment: xdiff is documented on php.net, as is using exec.  The diff commandline tools are also well documented.

Comment: That's great, but i still can't see any solution for parsing diff files.